# Containing a net with a compact set.

Tags: locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and let $(x_{\alpha})$ be a convergent net, say to $x$, in $G$.  Is it possible to construct a compact subset $K$ of $G$ which contains each $x_{\alpha}$ and $x$?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand; why not take $K = G$?  Or the closure of $(x_\alpha)$.  Any closed subset of a compact space is again compact; did you want $K$ to be a strict subgroup of $G$?

Comment: $G$ need not be compact.  But going back to the closure of $(x_{\alpha})$.  Need this be compact?

Comment: Oh sorry I misread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Consider $G=\Bbb R,$ $x=0,$ and the net $(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$--with $(0,\infty)$ directed in increasing order--given by $x_\alpha=\frac1\alpha.$ Any subset of $\Bbb R$ containing every $x_\alpha$ must fail to be bounded, so fail to be compact.

Comment: The context of my problem was I needed to be working in a compact set to apply a result.  I think the solution (to my unposted problem) is to take a relatively compact neighborhood of $x$, and work with the subnet of terms that lie within it.